# Time() shows "" rather than the current time string

Tags: delphi

```
Uses DateUtils;

.....

var d:TDateTime;
begin

   d:=Time();
   ShowMessage(DateTostr(d));


end;
```

it shows "" rather than the current time string

Your comment welcome

Comment: Why are you reading the *time* but showing the *date*? Try `TimeToStr` instead.

Comment: Are you *sure* it shows an empty string? And the question title is misleading, `Time()` doesn't show anything, and doesn't return a string. Its your `MessageBox` that is showing something and `DateToStr` that returns the string.

Answer (score 8):

You get odd results because `Time` returns a the date 1899-12-30 with the current time, and `DateToStr` returns the date as a string.

I question your claim that it shows an empty string though as it shows the following on my end:

[image: message box]

So you either need to return the full date and time like this:

```
d := Now;
```

but note that if you show the date, you're still not showing the time, so instead you need to show the time portion of the TDateTime variable instead of the date portion:

```
ShowMessage(TimeToStr(d));
```